# Returning different sub-types in a linq .Select() statement

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Let's say I have two classes in C# that derive from the same base class:

```
class Base {}

class A: Base {}

class B: Base {}
```

I'm working with a list of objects that I want to project to different sub-types of type `Base`. So I did something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Base> foo = myObjects.Select(o => {
  if(o.SomeProperty){
    return new A();
  } else {
    return new B();
  }
});
```

however, this does not compile, the compiler throws an error saying it can't infer the return type.

My question is: what is the most elegant way to specify the return type in cases like this? At the moment I've changed the lambda body to this:

```
if(o.SomeProperty){
  return new A() as Base;
} else {
  return new B() as Base;
}
```

this works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? You say you have a solution that works. What are you trying to improve?

Comment: Well, I guess I meant "more elegant" (see the accepted answer for example, it specifies the return type once instead of casting every time)

Comment: Oh, I see. But isn't the other answer "more elegant" than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good, you can also explicitly point types in Select extension method like this:

```
IEnumerable<Base> foo = myObjects.Select<T, Base>(o => {
  if(o.SomeProperty)
  {
    return new A();
  } 
  else 
  {
    return new B();
  }
});
```

T is a type of your myObjects collection here.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is okay but can be improved in two ways:

1. Use a ternary operator (`? :`) to turn the if-else statement into an expression.
2. The `as` keyword tests whether an expression can be cast to the requested type and casts it if it can and returns `null` otherwise. This test is superfluous here, since you know in advance that `A` and `B` derive from `Base`. Use a simple cast instead.

```cs
IEnumerable<Base> foo = myObjects.Select(
    o => o.SomeProperty ? (Base)new A() : (Base)new B());
```

---

An alternative, is to specify the generic type parameters of the `Select` method explicitly; however, it requires you to specify both of them:

```cs
IEnumerable<Base> foo = myObjects.Select<SourceDataType, Base>(
    o => o.SomeProperty ? new A() : new B());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 10 there is an additional option - [explicitly specify return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements#explicit-return-type) of the lambda which can be quite convenient in some cases:

```
IEnumerable<Base> foo = myObjects.Select(Base (o) => {
    // ...
});
```